# Confusion About Operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, linear-algebra

Hello I am currently studying introductory QM and am confused about bases and operators. If I have an operator $\hat{Q}$, does this represent a change of basis matrix? In other words, does $\hat{Q} | \psi \rangle$ for any state $ | \psi \rangle$ simply represent the expansion of $|\psi \rangle$ in the eigenbasis of $\hat{Q}$?

Answer (score 5):

No, an arbitrary operator does *not* represent a change of basis. And even those that can be used to perform changes of basis should not always be interpreted as such.

A "change of basis" in a Hilbert space is usually meant to be a change from one orthonormal basis to another. The operators that map orthonormal systems to orthonormal systems are precisely the *unitary* operators. But to speak of a *change of basis* for a unitary operator you have to simultaneously transform *all* states by $\lvert\psi\rangle\mapsto U \lvert \psi \rangle$ and all operators by $O\mapsto UOU^\dagger$. Just applying a unitary operator to a state is *not* a "change of basis", it is *transforming the state*.

As an example, all symmetry operators are unitary operators. So when you rotate a state, you apply a unitary operator to it. The "proper" physical interpretation here is *not* that you changed you basis, it is that you *rotated the state*. What pointed into the $x$-direction before now points into the $y$-direction, and unless you applied the rotation to *all states and operators*, you may not take the passive view and declared that you just switched the basis labels $x$ and $y$.